# Conversion from Mysql to oracle using Sql developer for oracle version 19c getting errors

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am trying to convert mysql (verison 8) data into oracle(19c) using sql developer but I am getting errors for most of the tables such as **inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER :**

I am having created date column with datatype timestamp in mysql while converting I am getting this error.Can anyone help with any tool which could handle this or for sql developer am I missing something ?

Comment: Most likely the format of the date is not the one oracle is expecting.

Comment: *I am having created date column with datatype timestamp in mysql* Alter TIMESTAMP to DATETIME.